# Construct a random string of n length from a list using Elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I have a list of strings that I want to use construct a new string of `n` length. How would I go about randomly selecting an elements from the list, and appending them to the string until I've reached the desired length?

```
parts = ["hello", "world", "foo bar", "baz"]
n = 25
# Example: "foo bar hello world baz baz"
```

Comment: How to treat this situation: `parts = ["ab", "1234"], n = 5`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `Stream` module to generate infinity sequence. One way to do it can be:

```
Stream.repeatedly(fn -> Enum.random(["hello", "world", "foo bar", "baz"]) end)
|> Enum.take(25)
```

This is elixir 1.1 due `Enum.random/1`. Take a look at `Stream` module documentation.

UPDATE 1:

to take chars with same approach:

```
defmodule CustomEnum do
  def take_chars_from_list(list, chars) do
    Stream.repeatedly(fn -> Enum.random(list) end)
    |> Enum.reduce_while([], fn(next, acc) ->
      if String.length(Enum.join(acc, " ")) < chars do
        {:cont, [next | acc]} 
      else
        {:halt, Enum.join(acc, " ")}
      end
    end)
    |> String.split_at(chars)
    |> elem(0)
  end
end
```

This one strip chars after `n`.

Comment: One more thing, from `Enum.random/1` docs: "Notice that you need to explicitly call :random.seed/1 and set a seed value for the random algorithm. Otherwise, the default seed will be set which will always return the same result."

Comment: Doesn't this return a list of 25 items?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I don't want 25 elements from the stream but rather the resulting concatinated string to be 25 characters long. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5):

Here's my go at it, this uses tail recursion:

```
defmodule TakeN do
    def take(list, n) do
        if length(list) == 0 do
            :error
        else
            do_take(list, n, [])
        end
    end

    defp do_take(_, n, current_list) when n < 0 do
        Enum.join(current_list, " ")
    end

    defp do_take(list, n, current_list) do
        random = Enum.random(list)

        # deduct the length of the random element from the remaining length (+ 1 to account for the space)
        do_take(list, n - (String.length(random) + 1), [random|current_list])
    end
end
```

And to call it:

```
iex > TakeN.take(["hello", "world", "foo bar", "baz"], 25)
"foo bar baz baz hello hello"
```